# "Could not find method com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCrypt.scrypt" But dependency declared in pom.xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

In my pom.xml I have this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
        <artifactId>scrypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I import it via `import com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCrypt;` but this code fails, giving the error I placed in the title:

```
public static byte[] scryptDigest(byte[] input) {
    try {
        return SCrypt.scrypt(input, input, 1024, 1, 1, 32);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using m2eclipse and I have ticked the dependencies in the order and export. This is an Android application. The exact errors:

```
07-03 20:03:42.564: I/dalvikvm(2600): Could not find method com.lambdaworks.crypto.SCrypt.scrypt, referenced from method com.rimbit.rimbit.core.Utils.scryptDigest
07-03 20:03:42.564: W/dalvikvm(2600): VFY: unable to resolve static method 30613: Lcom/lambdaworks/crypto/SCrypt;.scrypt ([B[BIIII)[B
07-03 20:03:42.564: D/dalvikvm(2600): VFY: replacing opcode 0x77 at 0x0008
07-03 20:03:42.564: D/dalvikvm(2600): VFY: dead code 0x000b-000b in Lcom/rimbit/rimbit/core/Utils;.scryptDigest ([B)[B
```

To be more precise, a library called rimbitj is using the lambdaworks.crypto library and then the rimbitj library is being used in the final application. Here is the "order and export" for rimbitj:

[image]

And the Android application:

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a runtime error. Are you sure that the scrypt library is being packaged in the deployment (APK)? I believe that APK files are just ZIP files with a different name, so should be easy to examine.

Comment: Are the libraries supposed to be compacted into the dex file?

Comment: I think I'm just going to use the command line instead. Android, Maven and Eclipse don't like each other.